# how to map mybatis exceptions to spring's using mybatis exception translator

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I read the [spring-doc#orm-exception-translation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-exception-translation), and add 2 beans as it says.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator">
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Also, my dao is annotated by @Repository.

```
@Repository
public class AuthorDaoImpl implements AuthorDao {
    private SqlSessionTemplate template;
    private MultiMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorDaoImpl(SqlSessionTemplate template, MultiMapper mapper) {
        this.template = template;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Author author) {
        mapper.insertAuthor(author);
    }

    @Override
    public Author getById(int id) {
        return mapper.selectAuthorById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Author getByName(String username) {
        return mapper.selectAuthorByName(username);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Author author) {
        mapper.updateAuthor(author);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Author author) {
        mapper.deleteAuthor(author);
    }
}
```

But when I tried to add the same data, what I get is still mysql exception. Could someone give me some ideas? Thank you very much!

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'obama' for key 'username'
```

Comment: according to [MyBatisExceptionTranslator code](https://github.com/mybatis/spring/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mybatis/spring/MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java), your SQLException has to be nested into PersistenceException to be handled. Set a breakpoint there to check the actual exception type.

Comment: Thank you! I found it's my fault. Spring auto translates the exception but I did't notice. When I catch the exception and see the class type I found it's DuplicatedKeyException.  @blackwizard